# Checking if div class exists returns an error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to web scrape from a webpage after I login some products with beautifulsoup. There is a case where product is no longer available. The webpage has a div class like the following only on page which has not a product

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <p>There is an error</p>
```

So I do

```
if soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'alert'}):
    print('Alert...')
```

or

```
if soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'alert alert-danger'}):
    print('Alert...')
```

**But I get 'int' object has no attribute text in the place of a product**

The status code of request is 200

How can I fix this and in place of empty product display something?

Comment: Your post is not clear at the moment. Please try to explain and share more code.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When I start web scraping the page there is a case where a product does not exist so the page displays a message under a div. How can I check and control this case?

Comment: At what point do you get an int? Can you show more code? The code that is in question should work fine

Comment: Have you got exceptions in your code? If yes just change print(e) to print('Alert')

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, maybe, this is your solution

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
p = '<div class="alert alert-danger">\n<p>There is an error</p>'

alert = 'alert'    

soup = BeautifulSoup(p, 'html.parser').div['class']

if alert in list(soup):
    print("Alert....")
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran the content of *if* from both your code samples:

```
soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'alert'})
```

and

```
soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'alert alert-danger'})
```

In both cases I got:

```
[<div class="alert alert-danger">
 <p>There is an error</p>
 </div>]
```

So I can not replicate your error. Maybe you use some old version of *BeautifulSoup*?

I have version *4.7.1*. Try to upgrade your installation of *BeautifulSoup*.

## Edit

Yet another method how to check whether your document contains a `div`
element with `class="alert"`:

```
if soup.find_all('div', class_='alert'):
    print("Alert....")
```

Note that the keyword parameter contains `_` at the end, in order to be
different from *Python* reseved word (*class*). This is a relatively new
feature of *BeautifulSoup*.